# Is there a way to generate a dynamic query when an user enters age (number) which display all the employees of that age?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

//model

```
const employeeSchema = mongoose.Schema({
name: String
dob:{ type: Date},
designation:String,
})

employeeSchema.statics.findByAge = function(givenAge){

var month_diff = Date.now() - this.dob.getTime(); //calculate month difference from current date in 
time  
var age_dt = new Date(month_diff); //convert the calculated difference in date format
var year = age_dt.getUTCFullYear();   //extract year from date   
var age = Math.abs(year - 1970);   //now calculate the age of the user

let query = new mongoose.Query();
query = this.find({}).where('age').gt(givenAge);
return query;
};
```

//app.js

```
let result  =   await Employee.findByAge(35);
console.log(result);
```

this throwing the following error

(node:13200) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTime' of undefined

Comment: What is `this.dob`?

Comment: dob is date of birth

Comment: Into an statics function `this` refers to the schema. I mean with "what is `this.dob`", what information do you want to get. The Schema are preperties, not values. So, what's the goal to get `this.dob.getTime()`.

Comment: I am new to this backend development using express and mongoose. I have saved 20 employee details having the above properties (employeeSchema) now my goal is to fetch only those employees whose age is above (say 35) and as the data type of dob is 'date' so its stored in yyyy-mm-dd format so inside the static function i used 'this.dob' to refer to a particular employee instance and used javascript logic to calculate the age from dob to current date. When i call this this static function from my app.js file it should return all the employees having age above 35.